# Python/Cython on Windows, CString causing issues

Tags: python, cython, cstring

`AttributeError: 'CString' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Scouring the internet doesn't find me much. AFAIK it seems to be part of Cython. Anyone who can point me in the right direction? Im also not getting much of a stack trace. (Inherited a fairly large django project)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure --- OP is asking about how to handle this in cython.

Comment: @Kasper --- please provide appropriate code samples so people can diagnose this problem (or use linked question if you want).